# Jquery Anything Slider - Cannot Link to External Websites

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plugins, slider

HI I installed http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#panel-4 and it works perfect.

But I cannot link a particular slide to a website. I tried the below code but for nothing..
Can someone offer an alternative?

```
<li style="width: 650px; height: 270px; class="panel">
    <a href="'.$slide['link'].'">
       <img alt="'.$slide['alt'].'" src="images/home_slideshow/'.$slide['img'].'"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </a>
</li>
```

The html/php parses good in the browser... so thats not the issue..
Does this support links ?

Comment: read the slider documentation, and show us how the link html looks like when its parsed

Comment: What's inside a slide should not matter, really. Moreover, if you say others are working, the problem lies in this particulr link. Can you post it? Also, but mybe it's a typo, you forgot to close the style tag, and 'class="panel"' may therefore not be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the style attribute.

```
<li style="width: 650px; height: 270px; class="panel">
```

should be:

```
<li style="width: 650px; height: 270px;" class="panel">
```

Whilst it may parse well in the browser, if the plugin you are using is looking for a "panel" class for an event then it wouldn't find it.

Also if this is in html and not being generated by php then you need `<?=$variable?>` rather than `'.$variable.'` as you've been using